# Query the facebook find-friends-browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to query the find friends browser (http://www.facebook.com/find-friends/browser/) with FQL or graph?

In order to search people that are p.e. from my hometown and not my friends, filter by gender, age or what ever.

Comment: Interesting question... However I do not believe that Facebook made this feature accessible via the API.